# Servlet info not picking up the full version on WebSphere

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, websphere

I have to generate a report which checks the type and version of the application server where the code is deployed. I was using `getServletContext().getServerInfo()` for the same which works fine for Tomcat and Web Logic, but in case of Web Sphere-WAS its printing IBM WebSphere Application Server/8.5 , whereas the version is 8.5.5.9. I do not know why the .5 is not getting displayed. Get minor and major version API's also do not print the .5 Can anyone help out. Below is a snapshot where we can see the actual version on the login page.[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour for WAS. This information is (indirectly) documented at this APAR [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM90025).

> The WASProduct API getServletConfig().getServletContext
>   ().getServerInfo() is updated to return the **correct server
>   information "IBM WebSphere Application Server/8.5"**.

In addition, the `getMajorVersion`/`getMinorVersion` methods return the version of the Servlet API that is supported by the particular servlet container. This is probably not suited for your purpose.

Outside of the Java Application, you can get the detailed information on the WebSphere installation by running `versionInfo.sh|versionInfo.bat`, which is available at `PROFILE_ROOT/bin`. Within a Java application, you can access this functionality by using the JMX interface exposed by WebSphere. See [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tjmx_develop.html) for an introduction towards writing such a program.

Comment: One question..The link that you posted above, in that it states that this will be a part of the 8.5.5.1. I am using 8.5.5.9, so shouldn't the problem be resolved. Also 8.5.5 is a major release after 8.5, so I should at least get 8.5.5

Comment: @Sid 1) As you are using 8.5.5.9, the fix for the APAR is already in place. That is why your output shows '8.5' as the version. The problem described in the APAR is that the value '8.0' was returned while running WAS 8.5. 2) v8.5.5 is not _exactly_ a major release. It is a Refresh Pack for v8.5, as listed [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036319). v8.5.5 restructures the Liberty profile as a seperate installation, which is the major change from v8.5. For the full profile, v8.5.5 is a typical fix pack.